# Util is not defined when referencing individual jQuery plugins (modal.js) via webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, bootstrap-modal

I have both modal.js and util.js be bundled in main.js(modal.js have dependency on util.js).

But when I load page with main.js, it through error "Util is not a function".

Problem solved.This issue is happening because bootstrap-4, doesn't respect UMD after the version v4.0.0-alpha.3. So referring src modal js file resolve the issue.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20709

Comment: what's your webpack.config.js?

Comment: Add my webpack.config.js

Answer (score -1):

just try it like this, it seems you mix the Case.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Util: 'util',
}),
```